# What is exit value 5 and why am I keep getting this error while running my C program?

Tags: c

Here is my `main.c` file:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "functions.h"

int main() {
    helloWorld();
    salaryPeriod();
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my `salaryperiod.c` file:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void salaryPeriod() {
    int wage, days, sp1, sp2;
    printf("Please enter wage:\n");
    scanf("%d", wage);
    
    printf("Days worked:\n");
    scanf("%d", days);
    
    printf("Salary period 1:\n");
    scanf("%d", sp1);
    
    sp2 = ((wage * days) / 26) - sp1;
    printf("%d", sp2);
}
```

And here is my `functions.h` file:

```c
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

void helloWorld();
void exponent();
void fourNumsProduct();
void salaryPeriod();

#endif
```

Does anyone know what is happening in my code?
I searched everywhere for exit status 5 but there is no result.
(Please go easy to me I am new to C)

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add a _complete and unedited_ transcript of exactly what you typed into this program and exactly what it printed out?  Could you also please provide us the code for the `helloWorld` function, so we have a complete program that we can compile and run for ourselves and watch it fail (in hopefully the same way it is failing for you)?

Comment: (Did you know that you can edit your question?  The tiny gray word "edit" under the tags is a button.  Yes, it's bad UI design.  Sorry about that.)

Comment: what OS running on?

Comment: Functions that take no parameters should be declared with the `void` keyword, e.g. `int main(void)`, `void helloWorld(void)`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There are several defects in your code:**

1. Ampersand sign is not provided to express a memory address in `scanf()` - the possible reason for your error:

   ```
   scanf("%d", wage); // should be scanf(..., &wage);
   ```
2. The variables like `wage, days, sp1, sp2` are local and visible to the function only. It cannot be used anywhere outside it (if you wanted so).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I didn't realize that my variables didn't have a "&" before it in the scanf arguments.